# How to do a regex replacement, adding characters in a date string?

Tags: php, regex

For PHP

I have a date I want line wrapped.

I have $date = '2008-09-28 9:19 pm';
I need the first space replaced with a br
 to become

```
2008-09-28<br>9:19 pm
```

If it wasn't for that second space before PM, I would just str_replace() it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = preg_replace('/ /', '<br>', $date, 1);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and the most concise.  Thanks  I also liked the idea you had below, but it could be made shorter with $date=substr_replace($date,'<br>'10,11)

Answer (score 0):

`s/ /<br\/>/` should do it. Though PHP regex might be greedy and replace all spaces.

### edit

I support Ben Hoffstein's PHP solution. Where possible, avoid regex as it nearly *always* has unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2008-09-28 9:19 pm';
$result = preg_replace('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (.*)/', '$1<br>$2', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex to match the pattern and return both parts, you can use the following.  However, considering all that you're doing is replacing only 1 space, try the [`str_replace_once`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#86177) that I'll suggest after the regex.  Regex is for complicated parsing instead of a wasteful use like replacing one space (no offense intended).

Please note that the following is browser-code, so don't attempt to use it verbatim.  Just in case of a typo.

```
$regex = '/([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}) ([\d]{1,2}:[\d]{2} (am|pm))/';
$match = preg_match($regex, '2008-09-28 9:19 pm');
print $match[1];  // Returns 2008-09-28
print $match[2];  // Returns 9:19 pm

// Or replace:
preg_replace($regex, '$1<br>$2', $date);
```

I suggest the following, much faster mechanism.  See [this post](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#86177) for the function [`str_replace_once()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#86177).

```
str_replace_once(' ', '<br>', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this, which is faster but a bit more code, is

```
$date = substr($date, 0, 10) . '<br>' . substr($date, 11);
```